# Creating Docker compose from docker run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using a **docker run** command as follows:

```
docker run  -p 8889:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook:57f8546c0386 start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

I need to change the same in docker compose file. I don't know how to add ***start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''*** in docker-compose.
Can i use it as environment variable??

Please let me know how can I include the same in docker compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command, anything that appears after the image name is interpreted as the command to run, and maps to Compose [`command:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command).

```sh
docker run \                                # docker options first
  -p 8889:8888 \                            # port mapping
  jupyter/minimal-notebook:57f8546c0386 \   # image name and tag
  start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''  # command
```

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  some_name:
    ports: ['8889:8888']  # docker run -p option
    image: jupyter/minimal-notebook:57f8546c0386
    command: start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

Just like with `docker run`, if the underlying image has an `ENTRYPOINT` declared, the command gets passed as arguments to the entrypoint to form the single main container command; and just like with `docker run`, if you need a shell in the container to process the command line (for example to expand environment variables) then you need to explicitly include a `sh -c` wrapper as part of the command.